# CSS animated Stripes not working

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

## Hey guys,

so i have 2 code snippets down below. In the first, i have beautiful stripes, they resizing themselves with the window size and are always centered (i try some animation but i dont get it like the animation from snippet 2)

But i need an animation, this animation are showed in the second snippet, the stripes should come from below and go up and I would like to keep that in the final result.

So i need a fusion with the first and second snippet.

### First:

```css
 html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        #position: fixed;
      }

      .mask {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
      }

      .container {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 -100vh;
        #position: absolute;
      }

      .stripe {
        float: left;
        height: 100%;
        width: 2%;
        margin: 0 1%;
        bottom: 0%;
        max-height: 0%;
        #position: absolute;
        background-color: black;
        transform: skew(-20deg);

        #transform-origin: bottom bottom;
       #transform-origin: left bottom;


        animation: ani 1s linear 1 forwards;
      }



      .stripe:nth-child(1) {
        animation-delay: 0.0s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(2) {
        animation-delay: 0.2s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(3) {
      animation-delay: 0.4s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(4) {
        animation-delay: 0.6s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(5) {
        animation-delay: 0.8s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(6) {
        animation-delay: 1s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(7) {
        animation-delay: 1.2s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(8) {
        animation-delay: 1.4s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(9) {
        animation-delay: 1.6s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(10) {
        animation-delay: 1.8s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(11) {
        animation-delay: 2s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(12) {
        animation-delay: 2.2s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(13) {
        animation-delay: 2.4s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(14) {
        animation-delay: 2.6s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(15) {
        animation-delay: 2.8s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(16) {
        animation-delay: 3s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(17) {
        animation-delay: 3.2s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(18) {
        animation-delay: 3.4s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(19) {
        animation-delay: 3.6s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(20) {
        animation-delay: 3.8s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(21) {
      animation-delay: 4s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(22) {
        animation-delay: 4.2s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(23) {
        animation-delay: 4.4s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(24) {
        animation-delay: 4.6s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(25) {
        animation-delay: 4.8s;
      }



      @keyframes ani {
        0% {
          max-height: 0%;
        }
        100% {
          max-height: 100%;
        }
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="mask">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
        <div class="stripe"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Second:

```css
 html, body {

        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: fixed;
      }

      .stripe {
        height: 100%;
        width: 2%;
        bottom: 0%;
        max-height: 0%;
        background-color: black;
        position: fixed;
        animation: ani 1s linear 1 forwards;
        transform: skew(-10deg);
        transform-origin: left bottom;
      }




      .stripe:nth-child(1) {
        margin-left: 0%;
        animation-delay: 0.0s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(2) {
        margin-left: 4%;
        animation-delay: 0.2s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(3) {
        margin-left: 8%;
        animation-delay: 0.4s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(4) {
        margin-left: 12%;
        animation-delay: 0.6s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(5) {
        margin-left: 16%;
        animation-delay: 0.8s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(6) {
        margin-left: 20%;
        animation-delay: 1s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(7) {
        margin-left: 24%;
        animation-delay: 1.2s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(8) {
        margin-left: 28%;
        animation-delay: 1.4s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(9) {
        margin-left: 32%;
        animation-delay: 1.6s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(10) {
        margin-left: 36%;
        animation-delay: 1.8s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(11) {
        margin-left: 40%;
        animation-delay: 2s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(12) {
        margin-left: 44%;
        animation-delay: 2.2s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(13) {
        margin-left: 48%;
        animation-delay: 2.4s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(14) {
        margin-left: 52%;
        animation-delay: 2.6s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(15) {
        margin-left: 56%;
        animation-delay: 2.8s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(16) {
        margin-left: 60%;
        animation-delay: 3s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(17) {
        margin-left: 64%;
        animation-delay: 3.2s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(18) {
        margin-left: 68%;
        animation-delay: 3.4s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(19) {
        margin-left: 72%;
        animation-delay: 3.6s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(20) {
        margin-left: 76%;
        animation-delay: 3.8s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(21) {
        margin-left: 80%;
        animation-delay: 4s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(22) {
        margin-left: 84%;
        animation-delay: 4.2s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(23) {
        margin-left: 88%;
        animation-delay: 4.4s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(24) {
        margin-left: 92%;
        animation-delay: 4.6s;
      }

      .stripe:nth-child(25) {
        margin-left: 96%;
        animation-delay: 4.8s;
      }



      @keyframes ani {
        0% {
          max-height: 0%;
        }
        100% {
          max-height: 100%;
        }
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mask">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
       <div class="stripe"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS animated Stripes issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43430191/css-animated-stripes-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a different approach:

- main container at bottom
- stripe container as a flex box with stripes align to bottom.
- animation on height

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mask {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin-left:-20%;
}

.stripe {
  float: left;
  height: 0;
  width: 2%;
  margin: 0 1%;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: black;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  animation: ani 1s linear 1 forwards;
}

.stripe:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0.0s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(9) {
  animation-delay: 1.6s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(10) {
  animation-delay: 1.8s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(11) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(12) {
  animation-delay: 2.2s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(13) {
  animation-delay: 2.4s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(14) {
  animation-delay: 2.6s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(15) {
  animation-delay: 2.8s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(16) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(17) {
  animation-delay: 3.2s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(18) {
  animation-delay: 3.4s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(19) {
  animation-delay: 3.6s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(20) {
  animation-delay: 3.8s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(21) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(22) {
  animation-delay: 4.2s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(23) {
  animation-delay: 4.4s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(24) {
  animation-delay: 4.6s;
}

.stripe:nth-child(25) {
  animation-delay: 4.8s;
}

@keyframes ani {
  0% {
    height: 0vh;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mask">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="stripe"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**note:** stripes can be direct children of body. you only need a single parent container for this.

Comment: Okay, it looks good, in the snippet. But if you put the CSS and HTML in an extra document and try this in the browser and change the window width as small as possible and the height as large as possible, you see what I wanted to prevent an empty corner in the upper left . I then changed your code. In the container: Margin-left: -20%; To margin: 0 -100vh; If you look now, the corner is gone and the stripes change perfectly with the window. You get the star anyway, because the animation now works perfectly.